# Menu doesnt work properly in smaller resolutions

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, drop-down-menu

I'm currently trying to get my menu to work on mobile devices/smaller screens.

The demo can be seen here > http://astuteo.com/mobilemenu/demo
Scale the browser window down and you'll see how I want it to look when mine is done aswell!

Here is my code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"xml:lang="sv">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title>egen hemsida</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="mobilemenu.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="screen.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".nav-button").on('click',function () {
            $(".nav-button,.nav").toggleClass("open");
            });    
        });
        </script>
</head>
<body>

<button class="nav-button">Toggle Navigation</button>





<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="#">Program</a>
  <ul>
<li><a href="#">Teknik</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Naturvetenskap</a></li>
<li><a href="#">El</a></li>
</ul></li>
  <li><a href="#">Nösnäs</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Schema</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Matsal</a></li>
   </ul>


<style>.xg_module_body img {margin:0!important;}</style>
<span class="bilder">
<div align="center"><table cellpadding="0" width="150"  cellspacing="0"><tr>
<td><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="facebookpic.png" title="Gilla våran Facebook sida" width="35" height="35" border="0"></a></td>

<td><a href="#"target="_blank"><img src="googlepic.png" title="Gilla oss på googlde+" width="35" height="35" border="0"></a></td>

<td><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="twitterpic.png" title="Följ oss på Twitter" width="35" height="35" border="0"></a></td>

<td><a href="#" target=""><img src="rsspic.png" width="35" height="35" border="0" title="Följ våran RSS"></a></td>
</tr>
</table></div>
</span>



</body>
</html>
```

CSS - Screen

```
.bilder {
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 110px;

}




* { margin:0;
padding:0;
}

html {height: 100%;}

body{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ccc), to(#fff));

}

.navbox {
    position: -9999px -9999px;
    float: left;
    background-position:-9000 -9000;

}

/* Första boxarna*/
ul.nav {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    width: 170px;
    position: relative;
    top: :0px;
    left: 100px;
    z-index:0;
    padding: 100px 0 50px 0;
    background: url(shad2.png) no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: 50% 100%;
    display: list-item;

}




li {
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/* När jag drar musen över */
ul.nav li a  {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;

    color: #174867;
    padding: 7px 15px 7px 15px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;

    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 2px #888;
}

ul.nav li a:hover {
    background: #ebebeb url(border.png) no-repeat;
    color: #67a5cd;
    padding: 7px 15px 7px 30px;
}
ul.nav li ul { 
display:none;
}
ul.nav li:hover ul { 
display:block;
position:relative;
left:5px;top:0px;
list-style: none;
z-index:999;
}

ul.nav li ul li
{ 
background:#888;

}
```

CSS- Mobile version

```
.nav-button { display: none; } /* hide the navigation button by default */

@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 475px) {

    /* Navigation Button
    -------------------------------------------------------- */

    .nav-button {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 7px;
        left: 7px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 35px;
        background: url('../images/menu-icon-large.png'), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.2));
        background: url('../images/menu-icon-large.png'),    -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.2));
        background: url('../images/menu-icon-large.png'),     -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.2));
        background: url('../images/menu-icon-large.png'),      -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.2));
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 21px, 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 0 none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.1);
        box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.7) inset;
        border-radius: 5px;
        z-index: 999;
        text-indent: -9999px;
    }
    .nav-button:hover { 
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1); 
    }
    .nav-button.open {
        background: url('../images/close-icon-large.png'), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.2));
        background: url('../images/close-icon-large.png'),    -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.2));
        background: url('../images/close-icon-large.png'),     -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.2));
        background: url('../images/close-icon-large.png'),      -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.2));
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 21px, 100%;
    }

    /* Navigation Bar
    -------------------------------------------------------- */

    body { padding-top: 50px; } 

    ul.nav{
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
        background-color: #238be3; /* change the menu color */
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.2));
        background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.2));
        background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.2));
        background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.2));
        display: block;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 998;
        clear: both;
    }
    ul.nav li {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        font-family: Arial;
    }
    ul.nav li a {
        display: block;
        width: 90%;
        padding: 10px 5%;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.1); 
    }
    ul.nav li a:hover {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        border-top-color: transparent;
    }
    ul.nav > li:first-child {
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    }

    /* Toggle the navigation bar open  */

    ul.nav.open { 
        height: auto; 
        padding-top: 50px;
    }
    ul.nav.open li { 
        display: block; 
    }

    /* Submenus – optional .parent class indicates dropdowns */

    ul.nav > li:hover > a {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
    }
    .nav li.parent > a:after {
        content: "▼";
        color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
        float: right;
    }
    .nav li.parent > a:hover {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
    }
    .nav li ul {
        display: none;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        border-top: 0 none;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .nav li ul a {
        border: 0 none;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 10px 5%;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    .nav li:hover ul {
        display: block;
        border-top: 0 none;
    }

} /* End Mobile Styles */
```

All I get is a little button that i clickable, but nothing comes out off it!

Thanks for the help everyone! :)

Comment: The link you added is not loading the style sheet at all. I do see the menu when you re size the window, that also seems to work just fine. In your jQuery, I would do this instead, `$(".nav-button").on('click', function () { });`.

Comment: http://astuteo.com/mobilemenu That the "main" site for it. Doesn't load the menu for me either. But thanks for the help!

Comment: Hmm, I tested it in IE, Chrome, and Firefox which all seem to work fine. Let me check it on my iphone. Works fine on my iphone as well.

Comment: Managed to get the menu to pop out, but at the same place as it in bigger resolutions! $(".nav-button,.nav") was wrong on the first one i sent!

Comment: Ahh I see! So you got it working?

Comment: Nope, changed the html code slightly, looks better, but it doesnät look close to the result I want! Hmm!

Comment: Weird it looks exactly like the picture for me beside the search menu.

Comment: Got it working now, finally! Also, while we're on the topic. Do you know how I remove the Box around the menu while it's not toggled? cause currently the box around stays forever.

Comment: The glow around the button is being caused by the tag it is, `button`. This is a default function for the `button` tag.

Comment: Glad you got it working, best of luck in your design mate.